# Access express-session cookie through socket.io

Tags: express, socket.io, express-session

I use express-session to store a session.id on the clients browser.
When using express .get function I can access this through req.session.id

Problem: I now want to access this session object through a socket.io connection. I've tried to use modules as 'express-socket.io-session' but they seem outdated. I also can't use redis as I'm on windows.

I'm really stuck on this problem, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try the following:

in the client:

```
socket.on('connect', () => {
  if ( !document.cookie) {
    document.cookie = "name=Wouter A";
    document.cookie = "occupation=student";
  }
  socket.emit('cookies', document.cookie);
});
```

in the server:

```
socket.on('cookies', cookies => {
  console.log(cookies);
  // or do something else
});
```